# Unknown field(s) (groups, user_permissions, date_joined, is_superuser) specified for Account

Tags: django, django-models

I just try add "is_saler = models.BooleanField(default=False)" into class Account and migrate. And now i got the error when trying to change the superuser data. The line "is_saler = models.BooleanField(default=False)" had been deleted but still got this error after migrate.

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have an username')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
        
    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superadmin = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    data_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
        return True
```

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GeVQ.jpg)
How can I solve this? Thanks

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Account
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
# Register your models here.


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'email',
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'is_active',
    )
    list_display_links = (
        'email',
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
        )
    orderring = ('-data_joined')


    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    Fieldsets = ()




admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

Comment: As the error says, the problem is with the `AccountAdmin`...

Comment: I just add the admin.py. I don't see which part is wrong.

Comment: I try to delete class AccountAdmin. It works and still don't know why that error occurs. Anyway, thanks

Comment: I guess you have to have a password unless you have done some medications in the Django authentication backend itself, And I can see you set the password=None in `create_user`, So that seems a little odd.